# Click A button faster

Tags: javascript, html, vps

We are playing a clicker game on a website where a button will be displayed at a random time, first 7 players to click it will be shown as the winners of that round. I wrote the clicker function bellow and always use it on my Chrome console.

```
(function () {
  setInterval(() => {
    const button = document.querySelector(“.click-button);
    if (!button) return;
button.click();
   }, 5);
})();
```

I was playing it with mobile network of 50 - 70 mbps of  speed  and was among the top 5 until when other players started using VPS Machine which have over 4gbps of internet speed. I now have a VPS running Windows server 2022 but cant still perform better. So My question is, Is it that my VPS speed is slower than their own or My Laptop have less specification than their own or I need a better javascript code than the one above?

Running the above code on a VPS server with a download speed of 4.3gbps and upload speed of 4.1gbps through a browser console and click faster

Comment: Transfer speed isn't ping. If your VPS is further away from the target server, it can be worse.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I just realised its a networking issue, are you a networker? can we talk privately?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't give private help sessions to people I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be a little faster by caching the function and the button outside the interval

```js
(function() {
  const button = document.querySelector(".click-button");
  const buttonClick = () => button.click();
  if (button) setInterval(buttonClick, 5);
})();
```

If the button does not exist at all, then the code above will not work. Then you do need the mutation oberver

Comment: I tried it but its not seeing the button, I guess it has to see the button for the first time before caching it. but what happens if the button is not visible( pop up) at the time of pasting it in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of polling for the button, you could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that will notify you when the button changes or is inserted into the document. Unless you can get to the event that triggers the button activation, this is probably the fastest you can do.

Assuming that the button is inserted into a `<div id="button-container"></div>`:

```js
const callback = mutations => {mutations.forEach(m => m.addedNodes.forEach(node => node.tagName === 'BUTTON' && node.click()))}
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
const container = document.getElementById('button-container')
observer.observe(container, {childList: true})
```

Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/bl1rt/pen/oNMyrrr?editors=1111)

Replacing the `forEach()` with a `for` will give you a few additional nanoseconds.

Comment: really very basic in programming can u just use my clicker example and write me a code containing the clicker? assuming the div id is "button-container"

Comment: @DeborahJames That's what the code above does. It watches for elements added to the container with id `button-container`, and clicks on every new element that is a button. Note that it only works if the button is added to the document. If it is already there but disabled, you need to watch changes to the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: I have tried this but keep getting this error on my browser console " Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. " Can u please drop me you social media handle or email or any way I can contact u? I want to give u my login details to the site so that u can take a look at how the button pop up and disappears. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. though am still not fast as expected but I somehow feel this method is way better because it just listens for changes in the div and click the button. I think the problem now is either the speed of the VPS am using or The laptop am using.

Comment: @DeborahJames Great that you figured it out. Yes, I assume that the network will ultimately be the limiting factor. If you haven't done so, you can gain a few nanoseconds by replacing the `forEach()` statements with a `for`, or just `mutations[0].addedNodes[0].click()` if you are sure that only the button is inserted.